# Azure Data Migration Tool

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, mlab

I am trying to migrate my mongoDB from mLab to Azure DocumentDB (with protocol support for mongoDB) using the data migration tool that Microsoft asks us to use, here is the link -https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436. The mlab mongoDb is trial version.

The connection string for mlab mongoDb is mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@host:port/dbname

But the tool does not accept the connection string for the mLab mongoDB but accepts the one for my local mongoDB.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: You might consider editing your question to show the mLab mongodb connection string you're using (minus your real credentials of course).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Added the connection string in the question. I will also add some screenshots from the Data Migration Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data migration tool is designed to migrate to standard DocumentDB accounts.  For migrating from MongoDB to a DocumentDB account with protocol support for MongoDB, I recommend standard MongoDB utilities such as mongoexport/mongoimport or mongodump/mongorestore.

Comment: Yes you are right regarding that it is made to migrate to standard DocumentDB and not DocumentDB account with protocol support for MongoDB. What I don't understand is flagging mlab connection string as one with invalid credentials when I click on verify for connection string. I am able to connect via RoboMongo/Mongochef to mlab using the same credentials.

Comment: I see.  The issue here is that the migration tool needs to use an updated Mongo nuget package for 3.xx support, it is currently using an older Mongo nuget package. At this point, I don't have an exact timeline in which that will be done.